# Unable to create grpc connection in 32bit windows machine

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, netty, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to access the list of Subscribers in my GCP Project using my java code and few libraries provided by GCP. This code works fine in my 64 bit Windows environment but not working in 32bit windows environment.

I have seen in a few documents, saying that netty is not supported on 32bit machines and we can build our own binaries if required.

https://netty.io/wiki/forked-tomcat-native.html#how-to-build

`CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider =
                FixedCredentialsProvider.create(
                        ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(JSONPath)));
        try (SubscriptionAdminClient subscriptionAdminClient = SubscriptionAdminClient.create(SubscriptionAdminSettings.newBuilder().setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build())) {
            ListSubscriptionsRequest listSubscriptionsRequest =
                    ListSubscriptionsRequest.newBuilder()
                            .setProject(ProjectName.of(ProjectId).toString())
                            .build();
            SubscriptionAdminClient.ListSubscriptionsPagedResponse response =
                    subscriptionAdminClient.listSubscriptions(listSubscriptionsRequest);
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"response List: "+response.toString());
            Iterable<Subscription> subscriptions = response.iterateAll();
            for (Subscription subscription : subscriptions) {
                if(subscription.getName().equals(SubscriptionId)){
                    return true;
                }
            }`

> [20:02:30:384]|[06-17-2019]|[io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts]|[INFO]|[36]: netty-tcnative unavailable (this may be normal)| 
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to load any of the given libraries: [netty_tcnative_windows_x86_32, netty_tcnative_x86_32, netty_tcnative]   at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:104)
>       at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.loadTcNative(OpenSsl.java:526)
>       at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.(OpenSsl.java:93)
>       at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.defaultSslProvider(GrpcSslContexts.java:244)
>       at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.configure(GrpcSslContexts.java:171)
>       at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.forClient(GrpcSslContexts.java:120)
>       at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.buildTransportFactory(NettyChannelBuilder.java:385)
>       at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:435)
>       at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:254)
>       at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:165)
>       at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.getTransportChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:157)
>       at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:157)
>       at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.stub.GrpcSubscriberStub.create(GrpcSubscriberStub.java:260)
>       at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.stub.SubscriberStubSettings.createStub(SubscriberStubSettings.java:241)
>       at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.SubscriptionAdminClient.(SubscriptionAdminClient.java:177)
>       at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.SubscriptionAdminClient.create(SubscriptionAdminClient.java:158)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [grpc-java SECURITY.md](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md#tls-on-non-android) describes your options:

1. Use Java 9+, which support ALPN without need for tcnative
2. For 32 bit Windows specifically, you can Conscrypt

The documentation also describes how to use Conscrypt. Namely to add a dependency on `conscrypt-openjdk-uber` and to register it as the default security provider:

```java
import org.conscrypt.Conscrypt;
import java.security.Security;
...

// Somewhere in main()
Security.insertProviderAt(Conscrypt.newProvider(), 1);
```

Comment: I used conscrypt-openjdk-uber-2.1.0.jar for my purpose. It worked good.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question... netty-tcnative-* does not support 32bit platforms so you will need to compile it yourself and include it in your class-path.